# Libraries from .GlobalEnv not available with spark.lapply

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr, databricks, sparklyr

I want to use SparkR / sparklyr to first do some data wrangling (+other functions depending on different R libraries) on Databricks. The main purpose is to do apply a function on every column of an initial dataframe and write it to a storage.
The only solution I found so far that would do the job is spark.apply from the SparkR.

In the function `writer` below other functions from different R packages or custom functions could be called.

```
library(SparkR)
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- createDataFrame(data.frame(rnorm(1000, 10, 5),rnorm(1000, 10, 5),rnorm(1000, 10, 5)))
inp <- c("COL_1", "COL_2", "COL_3")
names(df1) <- inp
writer <- function(x) {
             df2 <- df1 %>%
             select(x) %>%
             rename(INPUT=x) %>%
             #Adding additional columns is just a placeholder for other transformations taking place
             mutate(add1=INPUT,
                    add2=INPUT,
                    add3=INPUT)
             spark_write_parquet(df2, path=paste0(paste0("home/", x), "/"), mode="overwrite")
             }
spark.apply(inp, writer)
```

After all I would expect that the 3 dataframes are written to the defined directory as Parquet files. Unfortunately I get the following errors which seem to indicate that packages available in the global environment are not available on the worker nodes. I tried different solution attempts (installing and loading the packages separately on the nodes as described [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/346827/4305245754572172/936056/latest.html) or installing and loading them within the function).

```
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 14.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 14.0 (TID 44, 10.139.64.9, executor 6): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
Error in df1 %>% select(x) %>% rename(INPUT = x) %>% mutate(add1 = INPUT,  : 
could not find function "%>%"
Calls: compute -> computeFunc -> lapply -> lapply -> FUN
Execution halted
at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.api.r.BaseRRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:51)
[...]
```

Alternatively this message also occured:

```
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 134, 10.139.64.12, executor 6): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
Warning: namespace ‘sparklyr’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘’
Error in df1 %>% select(x) %>% rename(INPUT = x) %>% mutate(add1 = INPUT,  : 
could not find function "%>%"
Calls: compute -> computeFunc -> lapply -> lapply -> FUN
[...]
```

Unfortunately, none of my ideas have worked out so far... Hope for some help, thanks!

Comment: That's just not going to work. Even skipping over the fact that SparkR and sparklyr are not designed for interoperability, such nested processing is not supported in Spark at all. While you can _trick_ Spark into doing that, it is just [a recipe for disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155036/6910411). Looking at the overall structure, and taking into account lack of multithreading capabilities in R (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application), you should just parameterize the script with the column name and submit separate job for each column.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the input. I assumed that SparkR and sparklyr do not seem to integrate too well. Do you know how to pass arguments in `spark-submit` using SparkR? In Python I would use `sys.argv` but I can't find the proper function in the docs for SparkR... Thanks!

Comment: `commandArgs()` does the job!